# Finding the possible kernels of homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

Problem: What are the possible kernels of homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$?

I understand why the possible kernels are $0$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ if the binary operation is addition for both domain and codomain of the homomorphism.

However, would the answer be same if binary operation for domain and codomain did not have to be addition?

I cannot think of any binary operation other than addition now, but I want to know if we can generally find the possible kernels of homomorphisms when we do not restrict the binary operation on both domain and codomain to be addition.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Actually, it's very easy to imagine binary group operations on $\mathbb Z$ other than addition. Pick any infinite countable group $G$ with operation denoted $g \cdot h$, for $g,h \in G$. Pick any bijection $f : \mathbb Z \to G$. For $a,b \in \mathbb Z$, define $a * b = f^{-1}(f(a) \cdot f(b))$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that you define $x\oplus y=x+y+1$. It's a binary operation and $(\mathbb Z,\oplus)$ is a group. And the kernel of the identity function from $(\mathbb Z,\oplus)$ into itself will be $\{-1\}$ then. By a similar construction, for any $a\in\mathbb Z$, there is a group operation defined on $\mathbb Z$ such that $\ker\operatorname{Id}=\{a\}$.

More generaly, if $K\subset\mathbb Z$ is non-empty and $K^\complement$ is an infinite set, that, for some group operation on $\mathbb Z$, $K=\ker\operatorname{Id}$.

Comment: So does that mean the possible kernels are every finite subsets of Z? Could you give me the proof of your last statement please?

Comment: No, for example the complement of the even numbers is the odd numbers (which is an infinite set), so it satisfies the condition.